# How to run a selector when a button is pressed in UiAlertView

Tags: ios

So I have the following code and when the round is over it pops up with the following `UIAlertView`. Now when the user pushes the leaderboards button I want it to run the `- (void)` statement I have that displays the leaderboards. Please not that this is all inside of a sprite kit view controller. How should I do this?

Also I have my void statement in a different class, is there anyway to bring that over via an `#import`?

```
 - (void) gameEnded
    {
        // indicate our game state as stopped
        _gameState = STOPPED;

        // create a message to let the user know their score
        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You scored %d this time", _score];

        // show the message to the user
        UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Game over!"
                                                     message:message
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                           otherButtonTitles:@"Leaderboards",nil];
        [av show];
        // reset the score tracker for the next game
        _score = 0;

        //reset playing area
        [self removeAllBlocks];
        [self addBlocks];



    }
```

Comment: Delegates are bad, blocks are good! Here's a better way to use alert views. http://nscookbook.com/2013/04/ios-programming-recipe-22-simplify-uialertview-with-blocks/

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
// show the message to the user
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Game over!"
                                                 message:message
                                                delegate:nil
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Leaderboards",nil];
```

You need to set the delegate to 'self', or another class that you want be handling the alert view events as its delegate. That class must conform to the `UIAlertViewDelegate`, for example:

```
@interface YourController : YourControllerSuperClass <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

Then, Xcode will probably suggest you to implement:

```
– alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:
```

As this is the method called by the alert view on its delegate when a button is pressed. 
Here you'll receive a reference to your alert view and the index of the pressed button.
With this, you can find which action was performed.
For example:

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
   // In case there are more then one alert view and a reference to each of the alert views are kept.
   if(alertView == self.avAlertView){
      switch(buttonIndex){
         // Your button's cases!
      }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current `Controller` should implement `UIAlertViewDelegate`, and call the method `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` with the index of your `leaderboard` button.

Your `CustomController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AdsEventViewController : UITabBarController<UIAlertViewDelegate>

@end
```

Your `CustomController.m`:

```
[...]
- (void) gameEnded
{
    // indicate our game state as stopped
    _gameState = STOPPED;

    // create a message to let the user know their score
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You scored %d this time", _score];

    // show the message to the user
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Game over!"
                                                 message:message
                                                delegate:nil
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Leaderboards",nil];
    [av show];
    // reset the score tracker for the next game
    _score = 0;

    //reset playing area
    [self removeAllBlocks];
    [self addBlocks];
}
[...]
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(buttonIndex == _LEADERBOARD_BUTTON_INDEX_ ){
        // leaderboard method

    }
}
```